# c++ : confused as to why the compiler is giving error not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11

This skeleton example part of my code is causing the error 'x' not declared in this scope. I would have thought the computer would do both the Krow > 2 and Krow == 3 statements.

```
void GaussianElimination::JacobianFiller(){

    if(Krow > 2){
        double x = Y(0);
    }
    if(Krow == 0){
     //............. stuff
    }
    else if(Krow == 3){
        double a = x
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it is not? You declare `x` in the scope of the first `if` - it's not visible outside of the `if` statement - You can read up on scope in the reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: Each curly-braced enclosed block introduces a new scope. Variables in a block belongs to that block only (and *nested* inner blocks). Outer or parallel blocks do not share scope or variables.

Comment: Thanks, My problem is I don't want to rewrite the " double x = Y(0); "  Which is actually 5 lines of stuff in 3 different else if statements. I could make it member data of the class but the amount of member data objects is already huge. Is there a different way of extending the scope?

Comment: declare `x` at function scope? (Outside the `if`) - You can't change the scoping rules "by hand"

Comment: Yeah ill do that, ideally I only want to declare x if Krow>2 for speed.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: _I only want to declare x if Krow>2 for speed_ - don't worry about that. Local variables are very fast to create because compiler only adds an offset to the stack pointer. It may even store the variable in a CPU register only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that C++ uses [**lexical block scoping**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Block_scope) to determine in which scopes declared variables can be accessed: in short, this causes variables to only be accessible in the scope they're declared in, and in any nested scopes within that scope (after the declaration).

Since `x` is declared in the block following `if(Krow > 2)`, it is not visible outside that scope.

This can be solved by simply declared `x` in the parent scope:

```
double x; // declare x

if (Krow > 2) {
    x = Y(0); // don't declare new x, refer to existing x
}
if (Krow == 0) {
    // stuff
}
else if(Krow == 3) {
    double a = x; // x is visible here, because this is a child scope of the scope where x is declared in.
}
```

Instead of the above, you could also reorder your `if`s like so:

```
if(Krow > 2) {
    double x = Y(0);

    if(Krow == 3) {
        double a = x; // x is visible here
    }
}
else if (Krow == 0) {
    // stuff
}
```

This structure has the exact same control flow as the original one.

Answer (score 1):

You have different scopes in your code. The function is one:

```
void GaussianElimination::JacobianFiller(){
    /* Scope of the function */
    // This includes all other blocks of code in the function
    if(Krow > 2){
        // Still in the scope of the function
    }
    // More code...
}
```

Then you have your different statements in the function. I've chosen to exclude the function because these blocks do not see each other or the function. They only see what's inside their own scope.

```
if(Krow > 2){
    // You've created a local double in this scope
    // Accessing a function with an even larger scope
    double x = Y(0);
}
```

Same goes for this statement:

```
else if(Krow == 3){
    // Local double trying to access a variable outside of its scope
    double a = x;
}
```

Now as mentioned earlier the function have a larger scope. To solve your problem you make sure the blocks have access to the double x. By moving it up to the function's scope you'll have access to the double.

```
void GaussianElimination::JacobianFiller(){
    // Create local double in the scope of the function
    double x;
    if(Krow > 2){
        // Since we're still in the scope access the double
        x = Y(0);
    }
    // More code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward approach; do this:

```
void GaussianElimination::JacobianFiller()
{
double a,x;
If(Krow >= 4)
{
x=Y(0);
}
if(Krow == 0)
{
// .......... Stuff
}
else if(Krow == 3)
{
a = x;
}
}
```